# docker run nginx but can not browse to it

Tags: nginx, docker

On a AWS Amazon Linux which has docker installed. The following command is run,

`docker run -itd nginx bash` then
`docker ps` gave this:

[image]

But when I visit the server ip in the browser, it gives site can not be reached instead of th Nginx page.
How an I get the Nginx server page?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `EXPOSE` the ports and publish them to the host.

Try `docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -itd nginx` or `docker run -P -itd nginx`

Comment: I tried both commands but still the browser did not show the Nginx server page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had to remove the `bash` at the end of the command in order for this to work.

Comment: Right, you generally want to use the default CMD and ENTRYPOINT of a container when starting it. Specifying `bash` probably didn't start nginx within the container.

Comment: @antonEvangelatov i still face the same issue! any suggestions?

Comment: @aimal if you have exposed the ports through docker, but you still cant access nginx on your AWS instance, make sure you have opened port 80 on your security group/firewall.

Comment: @AntonEvangelatov solved my problem! I did add a port mapping and turned out that the IP which i was using wasn't the correct one. The correct one was 192.168.99.100. Thanks for replying btw!